# What is the best way to combine these datasets to get my desired format?

Tags: join, union

Doing some ELT work...
What is the best way to combine these sets of data into the form of the desired output:

Dataset A:

```
| project_id1 | types1 |  
A, apple  
B, banana
```

Dataset B:

```
| project_id1 | project_id2 | types2 |  
A, 15, strawberry    
A, 25, onion  
B, 5, peach
```

Desired Result:

```
| project_id1 | project_id2 | types |  
A, 15, strawberry  
A, 15, apple  
A, 25, onion  
A, 25, apple  
B, 5, peach  
B, 5, banana
```

And is there a name for this type of combination?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @zedfoxus data is from mysql... though i dont think database type should matter here when I'm doing ELT... I can use various different tools to do ELT and I can combine database types with those tools, so I think this should be database agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that information by doing so:

**Table**

```
create table da (
    project_id1 char(1),
    types1 varchar(100)
);

insert into da values
('A', 'apple'),
('B', 'banana');

create table db (
    project_id1 char(1),
    project_id2 int,
    types2 varchar(100)
);

insert into db values
('A', 15, 'strawberry'),
('A', 25, 'onion'),
('B', 5, 'peach');
```

**Query**

```
select * from (

    select da.project_id1, db.project_id2, da.types1 as types
    from da
    inner join db on da.project_id1 = db.project_id1

    UNION ALL

    select db.project_id1, db.project_id2, db.types2 as types
    from db
) x

order by project_id1, project_id2, types desc;
```

**Result**

```
project_id1 project_id2 types
A                 15    strawberry
A                 15    apple
A                 25    onion
A                 25    apple
B                  5    peach
B                  5    banana
```

**Example**

https://rextester.com/ISQA20343

I don't know of a name of this kind of data merging.

Comment: Thank you, although it isn't really in the format I was expecting, this will get the job done.

Comment: Awesome. If you feel appropriate, you can put a closure to your question by either waiting for other answers you could accept or mark this answer as accepted. Your choice.